# Print the middle line of any file UNIX

Tags: file, unix, text, printing, line

I have to print the middle line of any text file without sed nor awk.

For example, the following file.txt:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

I need something like:

```
$ command -flags file.txt
line 3
```

Is there any command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the most efficient, but works in bash.

Use `wc -l` to count the lines, and divide by two. Then use `tail -n +N | head -n 1` to print just the `N`th line (where `N` starts at 1).

```
$ cat input.txt
A
B
C
D
E
$ tail -n +$(((`cat input.txt | wc -l` / 2) + 1)) input.txt | head -n 1
C
```

Note that a file with an even number of lines has no single "middle line".

I `cat`-ed the file to `wc -l` so it wouldn't print the filename.

Comment: `cat input.txt | wc -l` could be replaced by `wc -l < input.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n $(((`cat input.txt| wc -l`/ 2) + 1))p input.txt
```

Comment: The question was how to do it without `sed` or `awk` right?